# How to remove icons from the BottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, bottomnavigationview

I just need the the label in my BottomNavigationBarItem's but I cant find a way to remove them.
You can hide the labels with `showSelectedLabels` and `showUnselectedLabels` set to false but there are no equivalent for Icons.

Constructor:

```
BottomNavigationBar({
    Key key,
    @required this.items,
    this.onTap,
    this.currentIndex = 0,
    this.elevation = 8.0,
    BottomNavigationBarType type,
    Color fixedColor,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.iconSize = 24.0,
    Color selectedItemColor,
    this.unselectedItemColor,
    this.selectedIconTheme = const IconThemeData(),
    this.unselectedIconTheme = const IconThemeData(),
    this.selectedFontSize = 14.0,
    this.unselectedFontSize = 12.0,
    this.selectedLabelStyle,
    this.unselectedLabelStyle,
    this.showSelectedLabels = true,
    bool showUnselectedLabels,
  })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better way I think is to configure the BottomNavigationBar. Just add this line and it will work fine. No need to add lines to each item

```
    selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(opacity: 0.0, size: 0),
    unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(opacity: 0.0, size: 0),
```

ex.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        label: 'Home',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.business),
        label: 'Business',
      ),
    ],
    currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
    selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(opacity: 0.0, size: 0),
    unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(opacity: 0.0, size: 0),
    selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
    onTap: _onItemTapped,
```

Comment: This seams like another solid approach. 
Probably more straight forward then the currently selected answer, so I'll change it to this instead.

Comment: please remove this obsolete solution. it's no longer working

Answer (score 11):

The key to this problem is to look at the individual `BottomNavigationBarItem()`.

If you insert a Container with a height of 0.0 as the title you get all the vertical space of the item for your icon or activeIcon. And since the `BottomNavigationBarItem` accepts **any widget** as icon or activeIcon you're pretty much free to use whatever you want.

In your case probably just a `Text()` widget like so:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: Text("My Item"),
  activeIcon: Text("My Item"),
  title: Container(
    height: 0.0,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Your right! It feels kind of 'hacky' but if it works it works.

Comment: Also just used this implementation to hide the icon and change it for a centered FloatingActionButton, it really feels hacky and I'll probably try to find a better solution some day, but for now it works like a charm. THANKS!

Comment: This is a solid answer and I have used it with great success, but the new answer is less hacky and requires less mental work to understand so I'll change it to the correct answer.

Comment: Not sure if/when the definition changed, but I'm using Dart 2.18.0 and `BottomNavigationBarItem` doesn't have a `title` field, it only has a `label` field which only accepts a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 params with `showSelectedLabels: false`, `showUnselectedLabels: false`,

```
  BottomNavigationBar(
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: '',
        icon: Text("Menu 1"),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: '',
        icon: Text("Menu 2"),
      ),
    ],
    currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.green[800],
    showSelectedLabels: false,
    showUnselectedLabels: false,
    onTap: _onItemTapped,
  )
```

Comment: I think you read the question wrong. I need the label to stay but the icon to be removed.  "You can hide the labels with showSelectedLabels and showUnselectedLabels set to false but there are no equivalent for Icons."

Answer (score 0):

After my experimentation, there are now two ways to achieve this:

As the BottomNavigationBarItem widget **doesn't** have parameters for `showSelectedIcons` and `showUnselectedIcons` currently, so there is no most direct way to hide it.

#### Method 1: Set the icon size to 0.

Set size 0 to free up the original icon space.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(

...

  iconSize: 0,
  items: [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart), label: 'Shopping Cart'),
],
```

#### Method 2: Use a Text widget instead of an Icon widget.

This method treats the icon as part of the text, and then adjust it to hide the original label, then can achieves the desired effect of hiding the icon.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(

...

  showSelectedLabels: false,
  showUnselectedLabels: false,
  items: [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Text('Home'), label: 'Home'),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Text('Shopping Cart'), label: 'Shopping 
  Cart'),
  ],
```