# how to add a text in bottom bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to write just a title in the bottom bar how to do that ? i want to write before icons the name of application
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 68, 109),

```
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.contacts),
        label: "back",
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.mail),
        label: "Emails",
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
        label: "Profile",
      )
    ],
    
  ),
```

Comment: icon accept widget so you can replace Icon(Icons.person) with SizedBox()

Comment: if you want display label only so try `icon:SizedBox(),` or `icon:Container(),`

Comment: if i do icon:SizedBox(), the label is not shown only if click on it how to make it visible ?

Comment: you want to display label only?

Comment: yes just the label

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60079744/8023701

Comment: see my answer below, hope its help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you.

```
items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
     BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: SizedBox(),
        label: "Back",
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: SizedBox(),
        label: "Emails",
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon:  SizedBox(),
        label: "Profile",
      ),
    ],
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: okay thanks in my case i want to display for example emails in the center and with red color with an incon back in the end how can i do it ?

Comment: what do you exact want?

Comment: a title wich is  in the center of the bottombar

Comment: have you test my code? its already center